# Changing project build target in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

I started building my android project in API level 15(4.0.3) and now i want to run it on my phone(2.3.3) so i downloaded all the files for it from the sdk manager but when i right click on project properties and click on android only android 4.0.3 shows up. any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Go to Window->Preferences in Eclipse then go to Android, this window lists all of your SDKs. Now open up the Android SDK manager and make sure the SDK Path (towards the top of this window) matches the SDK Location field in the Eclipse Preference window.